# Testing a [Flags] enum value for a single value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, flags

If I have an `enum` that's marked with `[Flags]`, is there a way in .NET to test a value of this type to see if it only contains a single value? I can get the result I want using bit-counting, but I'd rather use built-in functions if possible.

When looping through the `enum` values dynamically, `Enum.GetValues()` returns the combination flags as well. Calling that function on the `enum` in the following example returns 4 values. However, I don't want the value *combinations* included in the inner algorithm. Testing individual `enum` values for equality is out, since the `enum` could potentially contain many values, and it also requires extra maintenance when the values in the `enum` change.

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Four = 4,
    Seven = One | Two | Four,
}

void MyFunction()
{
    foreach (MyEnum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
    {
        if (!_HasSingleValue(enumValue)) continue;

        // Guaranteed that enumValue is either One, Two, or Four
    }
}

private bool _HasSingleValue(MyEnum value)
{
    // ???
}
```

Related: [StackOverflow: Enum.IsDefined on combined flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527486/c-enum-isdefined-on-combined-flags)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can cast it to `int` and use the techniques from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) to check if it's a power of two.

```
int v = (int)enumValue;
return v != 0 && (v & (v - 1)) == 0;
```

Comment: +1. While definitely not the most transparent technique, it's undoubtedly the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `IsDefined` and checking for powers of 2.

Comment: In the example I wrote, `IsDefined` would always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

You could you Enum.GetValues and count only those items that are a power of 2 (evenly divisible by 2 with no remainder).