# How do I check if more than one enum flag is set?

Tags: c#, enums

I just want to know if exactly one enum flag is set, not which ones. My current thinking is to check if it is a power of 2. Is there a better way built into enum types?

```
[Flags]
enum Foo
{
Flag1 = 0x01,
Flag2 = 0x02,
Flag3 = 0x04,
Flag4 = 0x08,
Flag5 = 0x10,
Flag6 = 0x20,
Flag7 = 0x40,
Flag8 = 0x80
}

private bool ExactlynOneFlagSet(Foo myFoo)
{
  var x = (byte) myFoo;
  return (x != 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0); //Check if a power of 2
}

if(!ExactlynOneFlagSet(Foo myFoo))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a solution.  `1010 != 0`, `1010 - 1 = 1001`,  `1010 & 1001 = 1000`, and `1000 != 0`.

Comment: Is there anything built into the Enums to detect if multiple flags set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: Wait, I'm a little confused-- are you asking how to find out if multiple flags are set or exactly one flag is set?  The title of the post seems to conflict with the body.

Comment: @mcintoda why don't you accept answers!? i see in your profile that you never accepted an answer, what's more simple than clicking that v and give the answerers the reputation they deserve and have the SO site more organized!?!?!?

Answer (score 75):

Its a Bit operation!

```
if ((myFoo & (myFoo -1)) != 0) //has more than 1 flag
```

The statement checks if the value of `myFoo` is not power of two. Or, vice versa, the statement `(myFoo & (myFoo -1)) == 0` checks for power of two. The idea is that only single flag values will be power of two. Setting more than one flag will result in a non power of two value of `myFoo`.

More information can be found in this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662162/2404788.

For more information about bit operations go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 10):

If the enum doesn't define explicit combinations of flags, you can just check if the value is defined in the enum:

```
private bool ExactlynOneFlagSet(Foo myFoo)
{
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Foo), myFoo);
}
```

Comment: +1: This works, even if the enum explicitly defines combinations (`enum Foo { None = 0 , A = 1 , B = 2 , C = 4 , AB = A|B , BC = B|C , All = A|B|C , }`). Specifying one of the predefined combinations ( `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Foo),Foo.A|Foo.B)` ) will yield `true`: it is in fact a defined value.

Comment: @NicholasCarey, yes, it will return true for AB, but AB has more than one bit set... The OP wants to know if there is more than one bit set, not if the value is defined.

Comment: Sorry Thomas... ive undo it. Its just that te idea of resolve a flag problem with enum methods doesnt like me to much... but your answer is correct in the end.

Comment: @MF., you can see it as a flag problem, or you can see it as an enum problem ;). Both approaches have their merits, but in this case your solution is clearly better.

Comment: Your answer shouldn't always be true, sometimes the user can set a combined field in the enum: `Flag4 = Flag2 + Flag3`, your function will than return `true` which is incorrect.

Comment: @Shimmy, I know, that's what I added a restriction: "If the enum doesn't define explicit combinations of flags"

Comment: @ThomasLevesque oops, sorry didn't see it.

Answer (score 8):

```
private bool ExatlyOneFlagSet(Foo myFoo)
{
  return !myFoo.ToString().Contains(',');
}
```

Comment: @MarkHall in .NET if more than one flag is set, the string representation of the enum is a comma-delimited list.

Comment: @MarkHall The Flags attribute make it show the individual value names separated by commas. You can go ahead and try it.

Comment: This seems dangerous because it relies on internal implementation details.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET Core 3.0+, you can use [PopCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.popcount?view=netcore-3.1), it returns the number of "1" bits in a `uint` or `ulong` and uses the `POPCNT` CPU instruction (if CPU supports SSE4, otherwise it'll use a software fallback).

```
public static bool ExactlyOneFlagSet(Foo foo)
{
    return BitOperations.PopCount((ulong)foo) == 1;
}
```

```
Foo one = Foo.Flag1;
Foo two = Foo.Flag1 | Foo.Flag2;

Console.WriteLine(ExactlyOneFlagSet(one)); //true
Console.WriteLine(ExactlyOneFlagSet(two)); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob explained in a comment your method is not correct at all. Personally I always avoid programming mathematically, especially when it comes to logic. So my solution would be something like "if I wanted to know the count is one, so count it and compare it to number one".

Here it is:

```
    public static bool OneIsSet(Type enumType, byte value)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<byte>().Count(v => (value & v) == v) == 1;
    }

    public static bool OneIsSet(Type enumType, int value)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<byte>().Count(v => (value & v) == v) == 1;
    }
```

And you can use it for your foo type like this:

```
   var toReturnFalse = (byte)(foo.Flag1 | foo.Flag2);
   var toReturnTrue = (byte)foo.Flag1;
   var trueWillBeReturned = OneIsSet(typeof(foo), toReturnTrue);
   var falseWillBeReturned = OneIsSet(typeof(foo), toReturnFalse);
```

I believe this methods could be written in a more generic way using Generics and type handling methods. However I included the methods for most common base types for enums which are int and byte. But you could also write the same for short and other types.
Also you may just inline the code in your code. It is only one line of code.

Also using this method you could see if the number of set flags is two or more. The below code returns true if the count of set flags is equal to 'n'.

```
   Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<byte>().Count(v => (value & v) == v) == n;
```